# How to make an array with random numbers, with one condition repeated n number of times?

Tags: arrays, numpy, random, conditional-statements

I have an array which I fill with random floating numbers from 0 to 1.

```
x = np.random.random((20,20))
```

Later on, I will extract the items in the array (x[row][column]) which are larger than 0.2,with this:

```
loc = np.argwhere(x > 0.2)
```

However,I cannot control the size of the `loc`. I have to have maximum 80 elements which are providing the condition of being larger than 0.2.

```
maxnum = 80
len(loc) == maxnum
```

And the `[row][column]` combinations of the items which provide being larger than 0.2 should be different each time, as it should be a random array.
To be more specific, if I would make an array :

```
y = np.random.random((4,4))
```

which yields:

```
array([[ 0.90282391,  0.11295454,  0.22650744,  0.31376307],
       [ 0.44553798,  0.19264588,  0.8944689 ,  0.77730786],
       [ 0.17462983,  0.79806749,  0.02074193,  0.3545992 ],
       [ 0.60130149,  0.5982725 ,  0.20522246,  0.99080217]])
```

I need only random 3 of them to be larger than 0.2.
Therefore, the expected output should look like:

```
array([[ **0.90282391**,  0.11295454,  0.12650744,  0.11376307],
       [ 0.14553798,  0.19264588,  0.1944689 ,  0.17730786],
       [ 0.17462983,  0.19806749,  0.02074193,  **0.3545992** ],
       [ 0.10130149,  **0.5982725** ,  0.10522246,  0.19080217]])
```

and the bold ones(larger than 0.2) their location should change in every run.

Do you know how to achieve that output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
n = 20
threshold = 0.2
maxNum = 80
res = np.zeros([n, n])
perm = np.random.permutation(n ** 2)

res.flat[perm[:maxNum]] = np.random.uniform(size=maxNum, low=threshold, high=1)
res.flat[perm[maxNum:]] = np.random.uniform(size=n**2 - maxNum, low=0, high=threshold)
```

Let me explain. We create an empty array `res` of shape `(n, n)`. We will have exactly `maxNum` values higher than `threshold`.
We select `maxNum` distinct indices between 0 and n ** 2 - 1 (I use `np.random.permutation` for this). We fill the corresponding values in a flatten view of `res` with uniform values between 0.2 and 1.

We fill the rest of `res` with values uniformly drawn between 0 and 0.2.

And so:

```
In [59]: len(np.argwhere(res > threshold))
Out[59]: 80
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I cannot have a single array with these codes? I wanted to create an array with 80 items being larger than 0.2 and the rest should be smaller than 0.2. With this code, I am having two different arrays?

Comment: No, you have one array `res`. We just fill it in two step.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you. In "res", right now, the numbers are uniform. However, the numbers should be random

Comment: @podedo  My mistake I forgot one argument

Answer (score -1):

This would help

```
l=np.random.random((20,20))
loc= np.argwhere(l>.2) if len(np.argwhere(l>.2))<=80 else np.argwhere(l>.2)[:80]
```

There if will data loss off course

Comment: This changes loc, not the number of elements inferior to 0.2

Comment: @podedo sorry could not really grasp your question :D

Comment: Thank you. But, how can I define "l" in here?

Comment: My bad @podedo. Corrected it